# How do you change your profile picture

Tags: discussion

Can anyone help I’m new to this and don’t know how to change profile picture every time I click change profile picture and click the picture or identicon nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

1. Go the main site, not Meta.
2. Click on your avatar.
3. You should see three menus on the far left:
   **Profile|Activity|*Edit Profile & Settings***
4. Click on *Edit Profile & Settings*.
5. There, close to center of the page, you will see a large image of your avatar, and at the bottom of it
   a button that says : "Change Picture".
6. Click on it that button. From there you can upload a new
       avatar image.

Comment: I’ve done that but no other avatars load except the one I have with a green tick next to it

Comment: What avatar would you expect to load? If want a custom avatar, save the image to your computer, then you can find on your computer through the 'change picture' menu and it will be uploaded to the site.